# Make a UserControl-derived class non-public

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In my WPF application, there's now a UserControl-derived class consisting of a XAML file and a C# code-behind file. This class uses another class of mine (which is not supposed to be public) in a public property. And Visual Studio always generates new control classes as public by default.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyType SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyType { ... }
```

This leads to the compiler error CS0053 (inconsistent access) because MyType is less visible than MyControl.SomeProperty. Actually, the control class has absolutely no need to be public, since this is not a class library but a normal application. And I don't want my other class to be public so that obfuscation will still catch it. Removing the "public" in the control class has no effect.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the *property* non-public, e.g. `internal`.

Comment: Simple and effective!